# Show that if all the normal lines to a surface pass through a fixed point, then the surface is (a portion of) a sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Show that if all the normal lines to a surface pass through a fixed point, then the surface is (a portion of) a sphere.

I'm not sure how to parametrize my surface.

In the book there is an example that says we can define a regular parametrization

$x:U \to M$, where $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $M$ is a surface

$x(u,v) = \alpha(u) + v\beta(u)$

From here if the parametrization is correct,

$x_u = \alpha'(u) + v\beta'(u)$

$x_v = \beta(u)$

<=>

$\alpha'(u) + v\beta'(u) - x_u = 0$

$\beta(u) - x_v = 0$

Then if we take the scalar product with $n$

$\alpha'(u) \cdot n + v\beta'(u)\cdot n - x_u\cdot n= 0$ <=> $\alpha'(u) \cdot n + v\beta'(u)\cdot n= 0$

$\beta(u) \cdot n - x_v  \cdot n= 0$ <=> = $\beta(u) \cdot n = 0$ <=> $\beta(u)=0$ <=> $\beta'(u)=0$

Therefore

$\alpha'(u) \cdot n + v\beta'(u)\cdot n= 0$ <=>  $\alpha'(u) \cdot n = 0$ <=> $\alpha'(u) = 0$

Since $\alpha'(u) = \beta'(u) =0$, then $x(u,v)$ is always a fixed distance from some point which means its the a part of the sphere.

Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry for not reading your solution. I just wanted to say that intuitively I think it should be easy to prove by first taking the fixed point $p$ where all the normal lines cross and assuming there are two points $a$ and $b$ at different distances from $p$ on the line.

Comment: Your example is a ruled surface. You cannot pick at random. Work with an arbitrary parametrization and use the normal vector, of course.

Comment: That is the part I am a bit confused about. How do I work with an arbitrary parametrization? I don't know how to write it down, and when I'm done know I don't have a projective plane or a connected sum of tori or something, only portions of a sphere. Is it possible still have something I can take the inner product of so I can show the normal lines of the surface go through the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis says that $x(u,v)= f(u,v)  N (u,v)$, where $f$ is a scalar, and $N$ the unit normal vector (if we fix the origin to be this point). We have to prove that $f$ is constant.

${\partial x\over \partial u }= {\partial f\over \partial u }N+ f {\partial N\over \partial u }$.

As $N$ is a unit vector, ${\partial N\over \partial u }$ is a tangential vector (derive $<N,N>=1$, as well as ${\partial x\over \partial u }$.
So computing the scalar product with $n$ we find ${\partial f\over \partial u }=0$, and similarly   ${\partial f\over \partial v }=0$, whence the result.

Comment: Okay I think I get this. Are you saying $x(u,v) + f(u,v)N(u,v) = P$, where $x(u,v)$ is some point on our surface, we take the normal of the surface at that point, then scale is by f until its the point $P$ we want. Then you use the chain rule and orthogonal relations to show the partial derivatives are 0 which means we have a portion of the sphere? That makes sense if I'm not missing something

Comment: jus read carefully : if the normal N pass through the origin at the point P, then $P= f. N$ where  f is the distance to the origine with a certain sign, say +. then derive to get that $f$ is a constant.

Comment: Hello Thomas, I think you can help me out with my similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115175/normal-lines-of-a-regular-suface-that-is-contained-in-a-sphere

Comment: But a parametrization, according to do Carmo's , is only a local property. How can you guarantee this parametrization cover all the atlas of the surface?

Comment: The distance to the origin is locally constant on the surface, so it is constant (if you assume that the surface is connected).