# Normal lines of a regular suface that is contained in a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider S a connected, parametrized and regular surface and $S = φ(u, v)$ Suppose that all normal lines of S pass through a point $P_o$ and write:
$φ(u, v) + λ(u, v)N(u, v) = P_o$.

Show that $λ(u, v)$ is constant and conclude that S is contained in a sphere.

I was told to use the following result:

If $f : U → R, z = f(u, v)$ is differentiable and $df_p = (f_u(p) f_v(p)) = 0$ then f is constant

However I'm stuck at how to even start to demonstrate it. May I have some help? I know that this question has been asked a few times but none used the result above.

Comment: They all use this result. There's always one standard method in differential geometry. Differentiate. You have a constant vector $P_0$. What do you know happens with a constant?

Comment: I'm beggining to learn about differentiability. For a constant vector, I would have (0,0,0). But what would I get from the left side? dφ(u,v) + ...

Comment: Keep going. You must have taken multivariable calculus if you're learning differential geometry. Make some efforts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note that $\partial N\over \partial u$ is a tangential vector. Indeed  $0={\partial \over \partial u } \langle N,N\rangle=  \left\langle2{ \partial \over \partial u } N,N\right\rangle$

2 Note that $\partial \varphi \over \partial u$ is also a tangential vector.

So if you differentiate your equation (apply $\partial \over \partial u$ ) an look just at the normal component,, you obtain  ${\partial \lambda \over \partial u }=0$, and the same with  ${\partial \lambda \over \partial v }=0$